# How to make a rpc request in node js to deluge?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rpc

I've been trying for the past couple of days to make an rpc request to deluge in node, without any success. The problem i'm facing right now is when I send a rpc request for example

`[1, "daemon.login", ["the_username", "the_password"]]`

deluge does not respond back with anything, the socket just stays open.
I've run deluge in verbose mode witch doesn't help at all. The only information deluge gives me is the client connected, it doesn't show me any errors. So what am I doing wrong?

The steps I've tried:

1. Zlib compress the data to send.
2. Bencode encode the compressed data.
3. Send it to deluge.

My Code:

```
var tls = require('tls');
var net = require('net');
var zlib = require('zlib');
var bencode = require('bencode');
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";

var toSend = '[1, "daemon.login", ["the_username", "the_password"]]';

new Promise((done, fail) => {
    zlib.deflate(toSend, (err, buffer) => {
        return done(bencode.encode(buffer));
    });
}).then(buff => {
    var client = tls.connect(58846, '192.168.0.22', function() {
        console.log('CONNECTED');
        // Write a message to the socket as soon as the client is connected, the server will receive it as message from the client 
        client.write(buff);
        console.log('Wroten');
    });
    // Add a 'data' event handler for the client socket
    // data is what the server sent to this socket
    client.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('DATA: ' + data);
        // Close the client socket completely
        client.destroy();
    });

    // Add a 'close' event handler for the client socket
    client.on('close', function() {
        console.log('Connection closed');
    });
});
```

Deluge rpc library in ruby: https://github.com/t3hk0d3/deluge-rpc

Deluge RPC documentation:http://deluge.readthedocs.io/en/develop/core/rpc.html